# Does livedata observer and databinding listener in xml file get triggered in parallel?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-livedata

If I had an `observer` in the activity and one in xml through databinding on the same `livedata` object, when I call `livedata.setvalue(value)` what will be the order that the subscribers get notified?

Answer (score 0):

`LiveData` observers [gets new data](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#update_livedata_objects) on the main thread, it's not parallel operation. Any case, you business logic shouldn't rely on order of observer's updates. If you need strictly control yours observers order, you need to implement *mediator* object and control observers throw it.